# Download and store Tableau View data in a cross-tabular format with the ability to apply filters and parameters using Python

Tags: python, tableau-api, tsc

I am working on connecting to a Tableau Server view in Python using the TSC library. I have successfully connected to the server and obtained the workbooks and views using the following code.
However, I am facing some issues in fetching the data from the view. Can anyone help me with this?

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import Authentication_Ana as A
import os

# Set up Tableau Server connection
tableau_auth = A.tableau_auth # TSC.TableauAuth('username', 'password', site_id='sitename')
server_address = 'https://anysite.com/'
server = TSC.Server(server_address)

server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth)


# Set page size to retrieve all workbooks
options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)

# Retrieve all workbooks on the server
all_workbooks, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get(req_options=options)



# Find the specific workbook by name
desired_workbook_name = "All Commissions"
desired_workbook = None
for workbook in all_workbooks:
    if workbook.name == desired_workbook_name:
        desired_workbook = workbook
        break

# If the desired workbook was found, print its name and views
if desired_workbook:
    print(f"Desired workbook '{desired_workbook_name}' found.")
    server.workbooks.populate_views(desired_workbook)
    for view in desired_workbook.views:
        print(f"View: {view.name}")
        
if not desired_workbook:
    print(f"Workbook '{desired_workbook_name}' not found!")
else:
    # Get the desired view by name
    desired_view_name = "Billing Credits"
    desired_view = None
    server.workbooks.populate_views(desired_workbook)
    for view in desired_workbook.views:
        if view.name == desired_view_name:
            desired_view = view
            break
```

I have successfully retrieved the desired workbook and its corresponding view from Tableau server using Python and TSC library. I now need to programmatically apply additional filters to the existing ones in the view, as well as set parameter values based on the dashboard configuration. After applying these modifications, I would like to save the view data as a CSV file in a specific location

something like below:

First, retrieve the list of filters and parameters available in the desired view fetched from Tableau Server. Then, apply the desired values to the filters and parameters. Finally, apply both the modified filters and parameters to the desired view, and export the resulting filtered view or crosstab to a local directory.

```
list(desired_view.filters)
list(desired_view.Parameters)

#Apply a filter to the view
one_of_the_filter_name= "Select Dept."
Select_Dept_value = "Analytics"

one_of_the_parameter_name= "View In"
View_in_value = "Summary"



filtered_view = desired_view.filter(one_of_the_filter_name, Select_Dept_value)
filtered_and_para_filter_view = filtered_view.parameter(one_of_the_parameter_name, View_in_value )


filtered_and_para_filter_view.to_csv('/local_path/file.csv")
```

The code snippet is written in Python using the TSC library to connect to a Tableau Server view and retrieve the desired workbook and its corresponding view. I am seeking help to apply additional filters and parameters programmatically to the view and save the resulting data as a CSV file in a specific location. The solution involves retrieving the list of filters and parameters available in the desired view, applying the desired values to the filters and parameters, and finally applying both the modified filters and parameters to the view. After that, the filtered view or crosstab can be exported to a local directory using the to_csv() method.

Comment: Did you manage to figiure out the solution? I have been trying to filter views before down,oading csv but haven't managed it

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC

personal_access_token_secret = '<Replace with your value>'
personal_access_token_name = '<Replace with your value>'
tableau_site = '<Replace with your value>'
tableau_server = '<Replace with your value>'

tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(personal_access_token_name, personal_access_token_secret,site_id = tableau_site)
server = TSC.Server(tableau_server)

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    request_options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)

    #Get list of views and IDs
    with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
        all_views, pagination_item = server.views.get(req_options=request_options)
        for v in all_views:
            print(v.name, v.id)

    #################
    #For single view
    #################
    #Download as csv
        view_item = server.views.get_by_id('view id')
        server.views.populate_csv('view id')
        with open('output.csv','wb') as f:
            f.write(b''.join(view_item.csv))
           
   #Download as PDF     
        server.views.populate_pdf(view_item)        
        with open('./view_pdf.pdf', 'wb') as f:
         f.write(view_item.pdf)

    ###################
    #For multiple views
    ###################
        ls = ['view id 1','view id 2','view id 3']   
    
        for l in ls:      
            view_item = server.views.get_by_id(f'{l}')     
     
#Download as CSV   
        server.views.populate_csv(view_item)
        with open(f'{l}_output.csv','wb') as f:
            f.write(b''.join(view_item.csv))

#Download as PDF               
        server.views.populate_pdf(view_item)        
        with open('./view_pdf.pdf', 'wb') as f:
         f.write(view_item.pdf)
```